# Can I get any info about my iTunes Connect customer?

Tags: app-store-connect

Regarding in-App (or other) purchases, is there any info available about the customer for a given transaction?

So far I've only found reports without any info on the customer.

It's important because how can we handle any customer requests in email without knowing if he/she has bought anything at all from us?

Answer (score 1):

I don't clearly understand if you're using iOS or OS X, but you should receive a receipt from Apple servers with a lot of information about the transaction, including info about the customer. You need to validate this transaction in order to confirm an in-app purchase. more info : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html

Comment: I'd like to get info on iTunesConnect.com, not from an API. By the way I'm afraid receipts also don't contain any info about customer name, address, email etc. ("of course" Apple won't give away email address, but maybe they could give some info about a customer...)

Comment: oh I see, I'm sorry I can't help you there I've only worked with API but you can search apple doc for more information. They must send something to id the customer not sensitive information like emails but something.